# Forefront TMG page denied display

Tags: microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010, microsoft-ftmg-2010

Forefront TMG - URL categorization reason not displays although it should be for denied pages.

I have tried all the available checkboxes on the Forefront rule regarding the message displayed with no result.

Looking in the ErrorHTMLs directory I believe that number 12231 should be in use.

```
<LI id=L_12231_12>IP Address: [IPADDRESS]
<LI id=L_12231_13>Date: [TIMESTAMP]
<LI id=L_12231_14>Server: [SERVERNAME]
<LI id=L_12231_15>Source: [SOURCE]
<LI id=L_12231_16>URL Category: [URLCATEGORY]
```

When I view the page source I am actually receiving I am however receiving a different set of values:

```
<LI id=L_default_12>IP Address: ...
<LI id=L_default_13>Date: 9/20/2011 5:41:51 PM [GMT]
<LI id=L_default_14>Server: ...
<LI id=L_default_15>Source: proxy
```

I am running version 7.0.9027.441, SP 1 rollup update 3. Sites are properly categorized - the log indicates the site categorization as expected - it is only the page displayed to the end user misbehaving.

For the life of me I haven't found a reason for this behavior. Why would this page be rendered in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With absolutely no change this corrected itself after reboot. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TMG 2010 + Software Update 1 + Update Rollup 4?

If not, which version are you on in Help/About?

And are you saying the URL categorization isn't displaying? Is URL categorization working at all, i.e. enabled and you can see categorized entries in the log when you visit a URL? If not, no category.